# Unable to start LLDB in Qt Creator Mac OS X

Tags: macos, qt, qt5, qt-creator, lldb

I'm transitioning to Mac OS (from Win and Linux) and today I got strange messages while trying to debug some code:

Unable to start LLDB "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/lldb": chdir: No such file or directory.

The LLDB process failed to start. Either the invoked program "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/lldb" is missing, or you may have insufficient permissions to invoke the program.

[image]

[image]

What's going on?

Comment: Check `Xcode` > `Preferences` > `Locations` and see if you have the command-line tools installed.

Comment: It seems Command Line Tools is installed.

Comment: If you open Terminal.app and type `lldb` or `which lldb` what is the result? It's likely a permissions issue with qt-creator that you'll need to resolve if the two commands mentioned work.

Comment: It seems lldb is there.

Comment: Maybe try the last part mentioned on this page: http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-debugger-engines.html#setting-up-experimental-lldb-support. Beyond that it's something specifically with qt it looks like.

Comment: I guess something related to permissions, I remember having to provide password to debug.

Comment: The password is only needed the first time the debugger actually attaches to/runs a program.  Shouldn't be needed to launch.  What does "xcrun --find lldb" say?

Comment: In a normal Xcode install, /usr/bin/lldb isn't actually lldb, it is a little stub that finds the lldb inside your installed Xcode and runs that.  That allows "lldb" to work no matter where you've installed your Xcode.  The above is to check that this linkage hasn't gotten messed up somehow.

Comment: `MacBook-Pro$ xcrun --find lldb
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/lldb`

Comment: And does that run if you launch it explicitly?

Comment: I moved the `.pro` file to the same folder as `.ccp` and `.h` files (before it was in `./build/project.pro` directory) and now it`s working. Hope this helps someone to solve this isssue.

Comment: @JimIngham, yes it runs from `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/lldb`.

Comment: Might want to report this as a bug to the Qt Creator developers.  It sounds like they reported the wrong error...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I set my working directory to a folder that didn't exist. Changing my working directory to an existing path fixed the issue.

Comment: I think this should have been a comment on the question and not an attempted answer, due to the unlikeliness that the problem could be reproduced after such a long period of time. The repro would be the thing that the OP would need to be confident in accepting the answer.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment :( I posted an answer not so much for the op, but for other people who get the same error (as I did) and try to google it.